# comparing two columns in a dataframe ignoring empty cells using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, series

I have a data-set which has few empty cells

|  |  | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | P | Q | R | S | T | U | result |
| --- | ---- | ------ | ------ | -------- | ------- | ------- | ------ | -------- |
|  |  | 4 | 3 | 14 | 20 | 6 | 1 | YES |
|  |  |  | 6 | 18 |  |  | 19.2 |  |
|  |  |  | 6 | 28 |  | 7 | 21 | YES |
|  |  |  | 7 | 21 |  | 7 | 23 | YES |
|  |  | 5 |  | 8 | 5 |  | 10 | YES |

Here Iam comparing (P,S) ,(Q,T) and (R,U) and I want to print 'YES' in the result column if values mismatch in atleast one comparison among the above three.
so far I did,

```
a1=((file_1.iloc[:,13]!= file_1.iloc[:,16])& (file_1.iloc[:,13].notna() & file_1.iloc[:,16].notna()))
b1=((file_1.iloc[:,14]!= file_1.iloc[:,17]) & (file_1.iloc[:,14].notna() & file_1.iloc[:,17].notna()))
c1=((file_1.iloc[:,12] != file_1.iloc[:,15]) & (file_1.iloc[:,12].notna() & file_1.iloc[:,15].notna()))

mask9 = (a1|(b1&c1))
```

But this is not printing 'YES' for all conditions! Kindly help me

Comment: If you want a1 OR b1 OR c1, then why `mask9 = (a1|(b1&c1))` and not `mask9 = (a1|b1|c1)`?

Comment: If I perform (a1|b1|c1) it gives True on row 1 because (6!= na).I want to ignore the row when either of the cell is empty.

Comment: "I want to ignore the row when either of the cell is empty" this should be in the problem description.